# React : Delete item from array

Tags: reactjs

I have the following:

```
const handleCheckboxChangeN = (checkbox, index) => {
    const addedgear1 = [...addedgear];
    addedgear1.Name = checkbox.Name;
    addedgear1.Weight = checkbox.Weight;
    const isChecked = checkedCheckboxes.some(checkedCheckbox => checkedCheckbox.value === checkbox.value)
    if (isChecked) {
      setCheckedCheckboxes(
        checkedCheckboxes.filter(
          (checkedCheckbox) => checkedCheckbox.value !== checkbox.value
        )
      );
      setTotalAmount((totalAmount) => {
        totalAmount = totalAmount - parseFloat(checkbox.Weight);
        return totalAmount
    });
    } else {
      setCheckedCheckboxes(checkedCheckboxes.concat(checkbox));
      addedgear1.push({ Category: checkbox.Category, Name: checkbox.Brand + ' ' + checkbox.Name, Weight: Number(checkbox.Weight) });
      setTotalAmount((totalAmount) => {
          totalAmount = totalAmount + parseFloat(checkbox.Weight);
          return totalAmount
      });
      
    }
    setAddGear(addedgear1);
    console.log(addedgear1);
  };
```

This basically pushes data through to an array if the checkbox is not checked. I am trying to sort the logic out for when the user unchecks it - it should remove the item from the array. I tried

```
addedgear1.splice(index,1);
```

But this uses the index of the checkboxes themselves, rather than the index of the order of the items added to the array.

My return map looks like:

```
{listItem.map((checkbox, index) => {
          return (
            <FormControlLabel key={index + checkbox.Name} className="twocolelement"
        control={
          <Checkbox
            key={`cb-${index}`}
            name={(checkbox.Brand) + ' ' + (checkbox.Name)}
            value={checkbox.Weight}
            id={checkbox.Category}
            color="primary"
            checked={checkedCheckboxes.some(checkedCheckbox => checkedCheckbox.value === checkbox.value)}
            onClick={() => handleCheckboxChangeN(checkbox,index)}
          />
        }
        label={(checkbox.Category) + ' ' + (checkbox.Brand) + ' ' + (checkbox.Name)}
      />

          );
        })}
```

How do I get it, so that if they uncheck the box, it removes this item from the addedgear1 array?

Comment: Do you have some unique identifier for the checkboxes you can use instead?

Comment: what is `addedGear`?

Comment: is `value` unique for every checkbox?

Comment: splice returns the removed elements and modifies the original array

Comment: No the value is not unique

Comment: Well if `value` is not unique then you cannot use it as an identifier like you do. Is there some other value that is unique?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend some changes to your code.
For starters, you don't need an extra array to keep track of the checked checkboxes, instead you add the property `isChecked` to listItems.
Second, you don't need the state variable `totalAmount`, since the value of it can always be extracted from `listItem`. When duplicating state like this, it makes bugs way more likely, and you also need to write a lot more code. Try something like this (which assumes that `value` is a unique value):

```
const handleCheckboxChangeN = (checkbox) => {
  setListItem((prev) =>
    prev.map((cb) =>
      cb.value === checkbox.value
        ? { ...checkbox, isChecked: !checkbox.isChecked }
        : cb
    )
  );

  const getTotalAmount = () =>
    listItem
      .filter((cb) => cb.isChecked)
      .reduce((a, b) => a + parseFloat(b.Weight));

  const getAddedGear = () =>
    listItem
      .filter((cb) => cb.isChecked)
      .map((cb) => ({
        Category: cb.Category,
        Name: cb.Brand + " " + cb.Name,
        Weight: Number(cb.Weight),
      }));

---


{
  listItem.map((checkbox) => {
    return (
      <FormControlLabel
        key={checkbox.value}
        className="twocolelement"
        control={
          <Checkbox
            id={checkbox.Category}
            name={checkbox.Brand + " " + checkbox.Name}
            value={checkbox.Weight}
            color="primary"
            checked={!!checkbox.isChecked}
            onClick={() => handleCheckboxChangeN(checkbox)}
          />
        }
        label={checkbox.Category + " " + checkbox.Brand + " " + checkbox.Name}
      />
    );
  });
}
```

Comment: I get listItem is not a function error?

Comment: on what line do you get that error?